# Get original unparsed command line as a single string?

Tags: php

Yes-or-no question: is the original unparsed command line as received by the `php` exectuable available to the PHP program as a single string in some way? I can fall back to imploding `$argv`, but I would very much prefer to have the Real Thing.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: This is a yes or no question. CAN the original command line be accessed or NOT? If YES, HOW? Do you know the answer to the question as stated?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. But it sounds like an XY problem, because it should never be necessary to do so. So what are you really trying to achieve which cannot be achieved by accessing $argv? Maybe there is a better way - that's why I asked the question

Comment: It is false that "it should never be necessary to do so", because it is necessary in my case. There is no better way. I must know the exact command line because I must re-execute a failing script in a debugger exactly as it was invoked, and the software system that launches the script cannot be persuaded to log the command. This is not a freak exotic scenario at all. You need to use a LITTLE BIT of imagination before you get to say that a question "looks like an XY problem".

Comment: If you want to re-execute the PHP command then using PHP itself to do that doesn't appear to make much sense (even to log how it was started up). Sounds like something you would do with an external script. If the script you're using to launch it doesn't have the capability, then replace it with one which does. If you need it to auto-restart the same command when it fails then use something like `supervisord`. It's an XY problem because you're trying to get PHP to do something it isn't designed for, instead of fixing the root cause of the problem in the launcher script.

Comment: `I know what my problem is, and you are only guessing.` ok so if you feel we do not have all of the information necessary to understand the situation then please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP tag on stackoverflow is heavily used, but no previous answers provide what you need and no-one has come forward to say it's possible. I also can't find anything in the manual about it, or anywhere else. What you want is 99.99% likely to be impossible, not least because in 99.99% of cases it simply isn't useful.

I work on various programming languages and none of them can read their exact startup command, they just receive the arguments.

You would be better to amend or replace the script which launches your command so it's able to log the PHP command it runs, and/or it could restart the command whenever it fails.